# How to auto check from one excel sheet into another

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, automation

So I have two excel 2010 workbooks one has names and phone numbers associated with those names and a seperate workbook that someone logs the name and times of the calls that come in (I don't know why they didn't ever write the #'s). I need to update on the second sheet with all the numbers matching to the names that called in. Is there an add on or a way I can auto match the names from the first sheet to the second sheet and automatically import the numbers? There are over 10,000 entries so manually doing this is not feasible.

Comment: VLOOKUP function being referred across the workbook is what you can use here, if all you need is to fetch the phone number from the first workbook into the second for a specific name entered in the second workbook.

Comment: Would I be able to do that with about 8000 unique names and the spelling slightly the same or would it only be exact matches?

Comment: It would be exact match, VLOOKUP allows option for Approximate match but that might give erroneous results. If you have 8000 unique names in a table, you will have to specify that  Table Array say $A$1:$B$8000 for example in the VLOOKUP function.

Comment: So let's say cell a1 is bob smith a2 is Jon Johnson and b1 is 9:00am c1 is where I'd like to import the numbers how would I do this with the vlookup? As you can guess I know next to nothing about excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your formula will reference a different workbook, you'll need to include the workbook and worksheet name in the formula.

Let's assume Workbook1, Sheet1 has names and phone numbers in Columns A and B respectively. And Workbook2, Sheet1 has names and times in Columns A and B respectively.

Type this formula in C1 of Workbook2 and fill down to list the phone numbers that correspond to the names in Column A of Workbook2:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,[Workbook1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$B,2,FALSE)
```

Replace "Workbook1.xlsx" with the actual name of the workbook that holds the phone numbers, and "Sheet1" with the actual name of the worksheet.

How it works:  the formula takes the name in A1 of the current workbook, finds it in Column A of the other workbook, and returns the corresponding phone number from Column B of that workbook.  The FALSE tells the formula to look for an exact match.

If the formula can't find an exact match, it will give a result of "#N/A".  You mentioned in your question that you may be interested in approximate matches. That can be done, but I'd suggest you try the exact match search for now and come back later with more questions or partial results.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the below formula rather than VLOOKUP, works great for me. You place the values in the first part that you want to pull across from the other sheet, and then use the MATCH function to find corresponding values, in the below example, the formula would pull data from the B column in sheet2 and match values from column A in both sheets.

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$B:$B,MATCH(Sheet1!$A:$A,Sheet2!$A:$A,0))
```